# Defining a Fact in Alloy which constrains an Airplane's capacity

Tags: alloy

I'm trying to define an Alloy Fact, in the below specification, which would prevent adding a Person to an Airplane's set of passengers, unless there's enough capacity. Furthermore, I would like to add another Fact, which would disallow the removal of a Person from an Airplane's passenger set, unless the latter's cardinality exceeded zero.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Phiroc

PS Here's my first stab at the initial Fact:

```
a'.onboard <= a'.capacity implies
    no p and add [a,a',p] and del [a',a'',p] implies a.onboard = a''.onboard
```

... According to Daniel Jackson, it's invalid because the condition before the *implied* keyword could potentially be false. Furthermore, it doesn't have the expected effect of preventing the number of passengers from exceeding the airplane capacity, when running the model. For instance, you sometimes get sets with cardinality 4, although capacity is 2, when you execute the model...

```
sig Person {}
sig Airplane {onboard: set Person, capacity: Int}

fact {
    some a,a': Airplane | disj [a.onboard, a'.onboard] 
}

pred show(a: Airplane) {
    #a.onboard > 0
    a.capacity = 2
}
run show for 10 but 2 Airplane

pred add (a, a': Airplane, p: Person) {
    a'.onboard = a.onboard + p
}

pred del (a, a': Airplane, p: Person) {
    a'.onboard = a.onboard - p
}

assert delUndoesAdd {
    all a,a',a'': Airplane, p: Person |
        no p and add [a,a',p] and del [a',a'',p] implies a.onboard = a''.onboard
}

assert addIdempotence {
    all a,a',a'': Airplane, p: Person |
        add [a,a',p] and add [a',a'',p] implies a'.onboard = a''.onboard
}

check delUndoesAdd for 10 but 3 Airplane
check addIdempotence for 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution.

```
sig Person {}
sig Airplane {onboard: set Person, capacity: Int}

fact {
    some a,a': Airplane | disj [a.onboard, a'.onboard] 
}

fact {
    all a: Airplane | a.capacity = 3 and #a.onboard <= a.capacity
}

pred show(a: Airplane) {
}

run show for 10 but 2 Airplane

pred add (a, a': Airplane, p: Person) {
    a'.onboard = a.onboard + p
}

pred del (a, a': Airplane, p: Person) {
    a'.onboard = a.onboard - p
}

assert delUndoesAdd {
    all a,a',a'': Airplane, p: Person |
        no p and add [a,a',p] and del [a',a'',p] implies a.onboard = a''.onboard
}

assert addIdempotence {
    all a,a',a'': Airplane, p: Person |
        add [a,a',p] and add [a',a'',p] implies a'.onboard = a''.onboard
}

check delUndoesAdd for 10 but 3 Airplane
check addIdempotence for 3
```